# Using Modernizr library, why does it add classes to the html tag

Tags: html, modernizr

Can anyone explain (because the github page doesn't) why Modernizr feels the need to add all of those classnames to the HTML tag ? After loading Modernizr, it looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class=" js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl ~~~~ etc etc
```

I see no explanation at all why it wants to do that. Modernizr provides properties to let me know whether for example canvas is supported (Modernizr.canvas == true?). Are those html classnames added for a test that's easier than that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These class names are meant to be used in your CSS code, so you can add fallback styles in case a feature is unsupported. Example from modernizr docs page:

```css
/* Simulated box shadow using borders: */
.box {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
   border-right:  1px solid #777;
}
.boxshadow div.box {
   border: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: #666 1px 1px 1px;
      -moz-box-shadow: #666 1px 1px 1px;
           box-shadow: #666 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to learn CSS. I thought I've always known enough about style properties, but this seems to be some advanced stuff.

Comment: I see someone voted this answer up. I guess that means it is the answer. I'll click the tick to mark it the answer even if I don't understand how/why it's the answer :)

Comment: @Dee2000, I voted it up as it makes sense. In this example, say your browser does not support drop shadows; .boxshadow div.box "should" never get targeted, so therefore, .box is used as a fallback

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong (and please correct me if I am), the classes here indicate the features that Modernizr has detected that are (or indeed are NOT) supported in the given browser.

Look at the docs here: http://modernizr.com/docs/

**Take this example:**

```
<html class="no-js">
```

if JavaScript is disabled, then modernizr cannot run, and therefore the class will remain `"no-js"` but if JavaScript is enabled, Modernizr will replace `"no-js"` with `"js"`, and similarly will tell you what other features are supported

Comment: I'll ignore the "no-js" one because it's a weird example. But what I'm not getting is why there's any point in adding these classes to the html tag when a method already exists. For example, when it detects whether video is supported, it ensures that (a) the property Modernizr.video is available that you can use in your JS to test, and (b) the class "video" is added to the html tag (for an unknown reason). The documentation doesn't explain why.

Comment: @Dee2000, I guess the idea is that you have html.flexbox for example in your CSS, which cascades through your document. but, if Modernizr never put "flexbox" in your html tag, it will never get targetted in your CSS...let me know if this does not make sense

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to learn CSS. I thought I've always known enough about style properties, but this seems to be some advanced stuff.