# Using Firebug, under <DOCTYPE> why is the first line <html class= "bunch of tags inserted here">

Tags: html

I wanted to view how other people code their websites, but got stuck trying to understand what this does:

```
<html class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange
             history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity
             cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent
             video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"
      lang="en" style="">
```

What is the purpose of this and can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: They are [using Modernizr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16138424/11683).

Answer (score 6):

Because they are using **[modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)**

**Modernizr** detects features which are supported and which are not supported by the browser. In response to it appends different classes `HTML` element. Which are then can be written as to fix cross browsers compatibility issues.

As `<html>` is document entry point or main container therefor it adds classes to `HTML` tag.

**[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914931/using-modernizr-library-why-does-it-add-classes-to-the-html-tag)**

Answer (score 3):

The classes in `html` tag is because of the `Modernizr` js included in the project.

Modernizr is a javascript plugin which on the fly identifies browser capabilities and respected classes on the `html` tag. For instance if the browser which supports `border-radius` property of CSS Modernizr adds a class named `borderradius` and if the browser does not supports `border-radius` it adds a class named `no-borderradius`, like wise for all other properties.

So when we working on project we can add a fall back design by targeting `no-borderradius` class for the browsers' not supported by `border-radius` feature of CSS3.

Comment: Targeting `no-borderradius` will treat browsers with javascript disabled as capable. (Just sayin'.)

Answer (score 1):

They're using modernizr for feature detection.

As a contrived example, if a browser didn't support CSS3 transitions, you could choose to add graceful alternatives. For example, you might check if the HTML element had the `csstransitions` class before adding any programmatically w/ js.

Modernizr also has a great set of useful javascript [methods](http://modernizr.com/docs/#s25). For instance, theres a method to test which vendor prefix you will need to use if any.

very useful, so you should

## [CHECK IT OUT](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing)